Let$f:R\to R$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in R$ and for all $t\ge0\; f(x)=f(e^tx)$ show that $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Let $f:R\to R$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in R$ and for all $t\ge0\; f(x)=f(e^tx)$ show that $f(x)$ is a constant function.

I do have a proof but am not satisfied enough if so want to make sure that it is correct. I am majorly concerned about $(2)$

ABOVE IS AN IMAGE OF THE ORIGINAL QUESTION
PROOF HERE
for $t\ge0\; e^t\ge1$. And since the functional equation is true for all $t\ge0$. Lets choose $t$ such that $$xe^t=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)$$
$$\implies f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)$$
Now applying the first principle of derivatives,
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h} = 0\qquad (2)$$
$$\implies f'(x)=0 \implies f(x)=c $$
Hence Proved! $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Take $f$ such that $ f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x\ne 0$.

f is supposed to be continuous i forgot to mention that @hamam_abdallah

The image has $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but your text has $f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.

@angryavian i will correct it the question in the image is the correct one

since $f$ is continuous you already know $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)=f(x)$ or am I missing something?

I don't think your argument works, you don't show how to get that $f(x)=f(x+h)$: the equality $f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)$ is true for all continuous functions. So it seems that you are proving that every continuous function is constant
Below is an argument; only continuity of $f$  at $0$ is needed.
Fix $x,y>0$, both nonzero. Assume without loss of generality that $x>y$. Then $x=cy$, with $c>1$. If $t=\log c$, then $f(y)=f(e^ty)=f(cy)=f(x).$ So $f(x)=f(1)$ for all $x>0$. With an entirely similar computation we get that $f(x)=f(-1)$ when $x<0$. As $f$ is continuous at $0$,
$f(-1)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=f(0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=f(1).$
Hence $f$ is constant.

i have shown how f(x)=f(x+h) and it indeed is quite similar to yours

Not the way you wrote it. You wrote "Let $t$ be such that $xe^t=\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)$. Said limit is $x$, so what you are saying is to choose $t=0$. That proves nothing.

well the question does states that it is true for all t's so i just chose it according to my convinience but it just did not feel right that way so i asked it if you can just explain it more elaborately it would be good as thats what i am looking for

After your edit, your argument got worse. The equality $f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x+h)$ is true for all continuous functions. So it seems that you are proving that every continuous  function is constant.

while what you are saying is true but one thing to note is that for all continuous function $\lim{h\to0}f(x+h)$ approaches f(x) while what i have proved is that they are exactly equal. There is a small difference just like $1^{\infty}=1$ but $\lim_{x\to1} x^{\infty}$ is indeterminant

There is no such proof in what you wrote in your question. The proof you need is something like what I wrote in my answer.

I doubt... The following is a counter-example. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{if }x>0\\
0, & \mbox{if }x=0\\
-1, & \mbox{if }x<0
\end{cases}.$
Clearly, $f$ satisfies the condition $f(x)=f(xe^{t})$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
and $t\geq0$. However, $f$ is not a constant function.

i missed to mention that f(x) is supposed to be continous

If $f$ is continous at $0$ and satisfies the stated condition, then
$f$ is a constant function. (We do not need to assume that $f$ is
contiunous at point other than 0).
Let $x\in(0,\infty)$ be arbitrary. Let $y\in[x,\infty)$ be arbitrary.
Put $t=\ln(y/x)$, then $t\geq0$. Now, $f(x)=f(xe^{t})$ implies
that $f(x)=f(y)$. In another word, $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$
and $y\in[x,\infty)$. In particular, for any $x\in(0,1),$we have
that $f(x)=f(1)$. This shows that $f$ is constant on $(0,\infty)$.
By continuity of $f$ at $0$, we conclude that $f$ is a constant
on $[0,\infty)$.
Arguing similarly, we can prove that $f$ is also a constant on $(-\infty,0]$.
Hence, $f$ is a constant function.
